# Rails application using bootstrap on IE9 looks fine locally but not on the server

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

On my local machine, I can see the rails application fine. But when I deploy to the server, it looks like it did not pick up the css. The fonts are not correct, the bootstrap left navbar is not displaying correctly.

I figured it was an issue with IE but why is it working okay on my local server on IE?  I have researched and have tried the recommendations of placing

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

in my `layouts/application.rb`.  I also attempted to inject it into the header by updating my `config/application.rb` file

> config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!('X-UA-Compatible' => 'IE=edge')

I also went and checked and saw that it was there on ie. But no luck.  It still will not display the css on the server but works fine locally.

I am using

rails 4.2.1,

bootstrap-sass 3.3.5,

issues are on IE7, IE8 and IE9  look fine on IE10 and IE11.

On IE7 - IE9 they look okay on my local but not when deployed to the server.

Comment: Try it in production mode on your local machine, it might be an asset pipeline issue.  Also make sure you've done the asset predeploy step.

Comment: Also you can use Firebug (or your favorite browser debug tool) to verify for sure if the CSS is getting loaded on your page in production.